# Cross domain ajax call is not working in IE

Tags: mysql, jquery

I am doing a cross domain ajax call.
This is inserting data in the mysql database.

```
var urlsearch = "http://192.168.10.113:8080/collective-intellegence/StoreClicks?userid=" + userId + "&query=" + query;
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: urlsearch,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
    }
});
```

When I run the above code it is showing an error message this

**XMLHttpRequest cannot load http: //192.168.10.113:8080/collective-intellegence/StoreClicks?userid=1&query=python&url=http://www.ourgoalplan.com/KLMS/TipView.aspx?id=1785. Origin http: //192.168.9.185 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.**

but data is successfully inserting the database in all browser except IE.

Please help to solve the problem

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @davidrac suggested, you can use JSONP as below:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: urlsearch,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'json.wrf'
    success: function (data) {   }
});
```

You have to add the `json.wrf` parameter to your query string with name of your callback function, to get properly padded response from Solr.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use JSONP or some other workaround.

See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) for explanation of the problem.

Comment: yes I already read these pages.
its working fine in all browser except IE 
can you please explain why??

Comment: Since you're not using JSONP, I assume this works since you added the Acces-Control-Allow-Origin header. MSHTML/Trident 4.0 (Internet Explorer 8) provides partial support via the XDomainRequest object. I'd go with JSONP to workaround this.

Answer (score 0):

When you are outputting the response from the server, add this header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

This will make the XHRs in IE to allow. For more information, please check [HTTP access control (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTTP_access_control).

In case of PHP, you can do it this way:

```
<?php
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
?>
```

Comment: I am using asp.net.
its working fine in all browser why not in IE??

Answer (score 0):

This code should work as long as IE is 8+ and the server response include the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: [Allowed origins]` HTTP header.

```
If (XDomainRequet) {
   //just an example
  var xdr = new XDomainRequest();
  xdr.open("post", url);
  xdr.send();
}
else
{
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: urlsearch,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
    }
});
}
```

Comment: how to use the above line in my code??
can you please rewrite the code with all js included.

Comment: It seems that JQuery refuses to provide native support for XDomainRequest, however several jQuery plugins are suggested to add this support. Google for it.

Comment: https://github.com/MoonScript/jQuery-ajaxTransport-XDomainRequest/blob/master/jQuery.XDomainRequest.js https://github.com/tlianza/ajaxHooks/blob/master/src/ajax/xdr.js https://github.com/Ovea/cors/blob/master/src/main/resources/com/ovea/cors/jquery.ie.cors.js