# solr is not working in IE

Tags: jquery, solr

I am trying to save data in mysql. By calling the solr url.
Its working in all browser except IE.

**My Code**

```
dataTable = "<ol>";
                //Check the data is present form the searching element.
                if (data.response.docs.length != 0) {
                    $.each(data.response.docs, function (key, value) {
                        dataTable += "<li><a href=\"" + value.id + "\" onmousedown=\"javascript:StoreClickedURL(" + userId + ",'" + encodeURI(userInput) + "','" + value.id + "')\">" + value.id + "</a></li>";
                    });

                    //Check whether persons there or not.
                    dataTable += "</ol>";
                }
```

**Function**

```
function StoreClickedURL(userId, query, event) {
var urlsearch = "http://192.168.10.113:8080/collective-intellegence/StoreClicks?userid=" + userId + "&query=" + query;
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: urlsearch,
dataType: 'json',
success: function (data) {
}
});
}
```

This is working fine in all browser but not working in IE(tested in IE7,IE8 and IE9).

It is not showing any error in any browser.I already tested this using Firebug.

When i click a link it is going to that function (tested by putting a alert in the function) but not storing data in the database.

Please help

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cross domain ajax call is not working in IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13303889/cross-domain-ajax-call-is-not-working-in-ie)

Comment: Did you implement the jsonp option ? and How is this related to Solr ? Its more of the Cross Domain Ajax call issue ? You are not even calling Solr here

Comment: then it's a script problem, not solr. print out the query string, before and after the ajax is called, that should give you a hint at least...

Comment: I allow my server to access cross domain

Comment: Samuele Sry i didn't get you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE doesn't support cross domain ajax call we have do this like below Code.

```
if (window.XDomainRequest) // Check whether the browser supports XDR. 
{
    xdr = new XDomainRequest(); // Create a new XDR object.
    if (xdr) {
        xdr.open("post", urlSearch);
        xdr.send();
    }
    else {
        alert('Server Error!! Try Later.');
    }
}
else {
    //Inserted data in the database.
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: urlSearch,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
        }
    });
}
```