# solr is working for my local iis not for hosted iis

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, jquery, solr, cross-domain

```
var urlsearch = "http://192.168.10.113:8080/collective-intellegence/StoreClicks?userid=" + userId + "&query=" + query;

//Inserted data in the database.
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: urlsearch,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
    }
});
```

this is working when i run the program in visual studio iis.
not when i run the code in a host website.
Means:

when i use

```
http: //192.168.9.185/KLMS/CustomGoogleSearch.aspx
```

url its not working in IE only.

but when i use

```
http: //localhost:56332/KLMS/CustomGoogleSearch.aspx
```

url its working fine in IE with a confirm message.

I am doing a cross domain ajax call.

Comment: possible duplicate of [solr is not working in IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13307309/solr-is-not-working-in-ie)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not working IE due to cross domain issue.

So you have to add XDomainRequest().
[See this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd573303%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)